# GitLab CE 7 behind Debian 8/Apache 2 virtual host: can’t access assets

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, mod-proxy, gitlab

On Debian 8.0 I’m trying to have Apache 2.4.10 manage a GitLab CE 7.10 Omnibus
installation as a virtual host.

## Setting and goal

Apache 2 is already set-up and running several virtual hosts that all look like
`vhost.example.com`.

I want to configure Apache and GitLab so that `git.example.com` gets
handled by Apache to display the GitLab web interface.

To that end I followed the procedure described in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25809733/4352108.

## Issue

I’m able GitLab’s main page on `git.example.com`, but I can’t access any
other resource such as CSS or icons. Apache logs show four errors that all look like:

```
[Sun May 10 20:24:57.146329 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 4141] [client 1.2.3.4:80] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/assets/application-TOKEN.css, referer: http://git.example.com/
```

After searching the web and trying several changes I got stuck here. Does anyone have an idea of how this can be solved?

## Configuration files

Additionally here are the “interesting” configuration files that I use:

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/git.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost git.example.com:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
    ServerName git.example.com
    ServerAlias git.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Location /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public>

        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted

        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080
        ProxyPassReverse http://git.example.com
    </Location>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* http://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
    ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
    ErrorLog  /${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.error.log
    CustomLog /${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.forwarded.log common_forwarded
    CustomLog /${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.access.log combined env=!dontlog
    CustomLog /${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
external_url 'http://git.example.com'
web_server['external_users'] = ['http']
nginx['enable'] = false
```

Some interesting enabled Apache mods:

```
proxy
proxy_http
```

Comment: `client denied by server configuration` I think you have permissions issue at OS level on the document root directory.

Comment: "web_server['external_users'] = ['http']" = if you are using debian, the webserver user is = www-data

Comment: @c4f4t0r: that’s right, assuming you kept the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.example.com
  ServerSignature Off
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    Require all granted
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://git.example.com/
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

</VirtualHost>
```

and try to change users from http to www-data

Answer (score 0):

In your **`VirtualHost`** file :

Replace

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

By

```
Require all granted
```

And your problem is solved